# Identifing differences among database objects in Cassandra

Tags: mysql, cassandra, migration

I'd like to implement a logic to verify if the `cassandra` has all databases and tables correctly after running my migration script. 
When I was using `Mysql`, I was using `mysqldiff` for fulfilling the requirement. 
Anyone who knows corresponding tools to `mysqldiff` for `cassandra`? Do I need to fetch all databases and tables for checking the accordance between my expectation and what `cassandra` having now?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no tools like mysqldiff for cassandra
But you can do this with cqlsh.

```
cqlsh ip_address -u username -p password -e "DESC keyspace_name" > keyspace_name.cql
```

Here `e` param means execute command and `DESC keyspace_name` will print the keyspace schema. you will get a `keyspace_name.cql` file containing the keyspace schema.

```
cqlsh 127.0.0.1 -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "DESC keyspace_1" > keyspace_1.cql
cqlsh 127.0.0.1 -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "DESC keyspace_2" > keyspace_2.cql
diff keyspace_1.cql keyspace_2.cql
```

Here diff will show the difference between these two file.